# Intro to chain rule - find two functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I'm learning about the chain rule in class right now. For a homework problem, we have four functions $h(x)$, and we need to find two functions such that $h(x) = f(g(x))$. My question is, how do I find **two** different functions for each problem by using the chain rule?

Here are two of the problems:
$$h(x) = (4x + 1)^{15}$$

$$h(x) = e^{3x^2}$$

Comment: $ \text{ If I say } h(x)=(g(x))^{15} \text{ where } h(x)=f(g(x)) \\ \text{ would you know what to call } f(x) \text{?}$

Comment: Are you actually using chain rule? Are trying to identify f(x) and g(x) such that h(x)=f(g(x))?

Comment: @randomgirl Yes

Comment: Here's an example: if $h(x) = \sin(x^3)$, then $h(x) = f(g(x))$, where $g(x) = x^3$ and $f(y) = \sin(y)$.  Another example: if $h(x) = \log(x + x^5)$, then $h(x) = f(g(x))$ where $g(x) = x + x^5$ and $f(y) = \log(y)$.  We are not using the chain rule yet, we are only preparing to use the chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $h_1(x) = (4x+1)^{15}$, your two functions should be $f(x) = x^{15}$ and $g(x) = 4x+1$, because then $f(g(x)) = (4x+1)^{15}$.  This will be the easiest decomposition.

Though, if you really wanted, you could even do more chains rules here, by specifying even more functions.  Let $a(x) = x$, $b(x) = 4x$, $c(x) = x+1$, and $d(x) = x^{15}$.  Then $$a(x) = x \implies b(a(x))=b(x) = 4x \implies c(b(a(x))) = c(b(x)) = c(4x) = 4x+1$$ $$\implies d(c(b(a(x)))) = d(c(b(x))) = d(c(4x)) = d(4x+1) = (4x+1)^{15}$$

Or you could also let $j(x) = 2x$, $k(x)= 2x+1$, and $m(x)=x^{15}$.  Then $m(k(j(x))) = (2(2x)+1)^{15}=(4x+1)^{15}$.

Or you could let $n(x) = (4x+1)^3$ and $p(x) = x^5$ because then $p(n(x)) = ((4x+1)^3)^5 = (4x+1)^{15}$ -- but this isn't very useful because $(4x+1)^3$ doesn't have an obvious derivative.

Now can you figure out two functions $f$ and $g$ for $h_2(x) = e^{3x^2}$?

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you, I was able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Think of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as layers. So, if $h(x) = f(g(x))$, then $f(x)$ is the outer "layer" and $g(x)$ is the inner "layer". If I take the derivative of a function $g(x) = 4x+1$, I am taking the derivative of $4x + 1$ with respect to $x$ or $\frac{d}{dx} (4x + 1)$. But, if I take the derivative of $f(u)$, where $u = g(x)$, I would be taking the derivative of $f(u) = u^{15}$ with respect to $u$ or $\frac{d}{du} u^{15}$. However, we did not want to take the derivative with respect to $u$. We wanted to take it with respect to $x$. In order to do that, we would have to multiply $\frac{d}{du}\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}$. 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (4x+1)^{15} = \frac{d}{du} u^{15}\frac{du}{dx}, u = g(x), u^{15} = f(x)\\
\frac{du}{dx} = g^{\prime}(x) = 4\\
\frac{d}{du} u^{15} = 15u^{14}\\
$$
substitute everything back in
$$
15(4x+1)^{14} \cdot 4 = 60(4x+1)^{14}
$$